# Problems with showing listView in fragment after orientation change

Tags: android, listview, orientation, fragment

Im trying to create a simple app with two fragments, one from left with a list of items, on the right details from the left selected element. It works fine, but when i change the orientation of my device then some position of list is "freezed" on background. Can anyone help me?

My activity's onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("on ", "createActivity");
    FragmentTransaction fTrans=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.add(R.id.frame1, fragmentList);
    fTrans.add(R.id.frame2, detailFragment);
    //detailFragment.setData("name 0", "src 0",   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    fTrans.commit();
```

DetailFragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
private TextView tv1;
private TextView tv2;
private ImageView iw;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment , container, false);
    tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.detailText1);
    tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.detailText2);
    iw=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.detailImage);
    return view;
}
public void setData(String text1, String text2, Bitmap bmp) {
    tv1.setText(text1);
    tv2.setText(text2);
    iw.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

ListFragment:

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
String[] from={"name", "imageSource", "image"};
int[] to={R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.imageView};
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    HashMap<String, Object> m=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(int i=0; i<=19; i++) {
        m=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put("name", "name "+i);
        m.put("imageSource", "src "+i);
        m.put("image", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        list.add(m);
    }
    Log.i("on ", "createView");
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);
    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.row, from, to);
    ListView listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            DetailFragment df=(DetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame2);
            df.setData((String)list.get(i).get("name"), (String)list.get(i).get("imageSource"), (Bitmap)list.get(i).get("image"));


        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image: listview]

try changing your transaction's **add** to **replace**:

```
FragmentTransaction fTrans=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.replace(R.id.frame1, fragmentList);
```

When orientation changes, onCreate() is overwriting the listview fragment without removing the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
```

try in your manifest this in application tag  as :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

i was not elaborating because of my english . this is for if you want no change is to be happen if orientation is changed .

Comment: You _could_ elaborate more. Hit edit and explain why this is an answer.

Comment: in your manifest file in application tag <application android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" ... ../>

Comment: You did not understood my question. I meen i want changing the orientation, and it changes, but the list on the left side is just "freeze" on the background(i meen that i can scroll the list, but in the background you will see a prev position of the list), sorry but yet i cant post screenshots